# CSS Only Tooltip Problem

Tags: css, tooltip

Have been using a simple CSS only tooltip.

Working Example
css:

```
.tip
{
    position:relative;
}
.tip span.tooltip
{
    display:none;
    background:#ff5112;
    border:1px solid #9C0;
}
.tip:hover span.tooltip
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:2em; left:2em; width:15em;
    border:1px solid #0cf;
    background-color:#cff; color:#000;
    text-align: center
}
```

html:

```
<span class="tip">
<table><tr>
<td>Working Tip</td><span class="tooltip">Tip</span>  
</tr></table>
</span>
```

Not working example:
html:

```
<table><tr>
<span class="tip"><td>Not working TIP</td><span class="tooltip">Tip</span></span>
</tr></table>
```

And a [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/8SHp5/)

Comment: What's your question? I think you need to include your code in a `code-block` as you appear to have lost your formatting?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code to a code block. I cannot see the difference between working and non-working code otherwise.

Comment: Also, IIRC, table nested within span isn't allowed, as span is inline, and table is block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the table element - you cannot have a span that wraps <td>. Get rid of the table and everything will work.

Comment: i wanted tooltips for data in a table.

Comment: Then put everything inside the <td> element. <td><span class="tip">Some text<span class="tooltip">Tooltip</span></span></td>.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your tooltip css class, try adding one

Answer (score 1):

table within a span is not allowed, try fixing that

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe I see your question but since the question is omitted, I'll take a shot. The second example is mal-formatted if you really wanted something to that extent it should be more like:

```
<span class="tip">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Working Tip</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <span class="tooltip">Tip</span>  
</span>
```

If you are going to wrap the entire table the "tip" should be after the table tag.

Comment: bull-ox! how did that post happen and get "2" ups already it must have been posted at the same time as mine geez. sorry for the same answer then.

Answer (score 0):

`<span class="tooltip">` needs to go inside of `<td class="tip">` for your current CSS to work as expected...

```
<table><tr> 
  <td class="tip">
    Working Tip
    <span class="tooltip">Tip</span>
  </td>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me:

```
<table><tr><td>
<a href="blah.php" class="tip">
Blah Blah Text
<span class="tooltip">Blah Blah Tip</span>
</a>
</td></tr></table>
```

But this looks really bad with css turned off, so the way to go will be using the title attribute and then adding mootools or such libs on the top.

Thank you guys.